# GLKit View Controller poor performance

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I used to draw some animations using hand-written initialization of frame and render buffers and rendering loop. Now i am trying to move my stuff to GLKit View Controller , but i am getting horribly bad performance in some cases, comparatively to my previous application.

My animation is separated into four scenes, each of them has it's own vertex and fragment shaders, vertex and texture data, gl program, etc. There is also a class defining which scene should be rendered at the moment, so it creates and destroys instances of them when necessary. I only call
`[sceneManager draw]` in my rendering loop.

So, moving to GLKit View Controller, i subclassed it and just added this call like:

```
-(void) glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (!_myManagerInstance.animationFinished) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

        [_myManagerInstance draw];
    } else {
        self.paused=true;
    }
}
```

It works ok, but the animation lags notably (about 15 FPS in worst cases). Profiling the app for OpenGLES performance showed large amount of redundant calls, which are not coming from my code, [see the image](http://postimage.org/image/6txr8bwvt/). I also found [this post](http://blog.world-of-towers.com/first-opengl-profiling/) of a person having the same problems. So, am i even using GLKit VC in the right way? Or am i just missing some configuration?

Comment: In situations like this it can help to look at what GLKit returns for the framesPerSecond property, to isolate the issue.